# Repeat Notifications monthly on specific day

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I want to repeat notifications monthly on a specific day, but my concern is, what if the user chooses the 31? Then the Notification would only fire every 2 months and never in February?
Because the day component would not match.

Is it possible to set the day to the last day of the month, so when for example February is the next month and the user selected the 31. then it would fire on the last day of February?

I could go the non repeating way and add the notifications manually, but then i would have to face the 64 scheduled notification limit.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: we had the same problem. It is not possible to use it in repeat mode. You need to set it manually if you want to fire notification on the last date. For 64 limitations, you can update the notification when the user opens the app once a day or update monthly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Calendar` module is the way to go. Handling dates manually can get very tricky.

```
import Calendar

let selectedDate = "31/01/2020"

// Convert string to Date
let dateF = DateFormatter()
dateF.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let myDate = dateF.date(from: selectedDate)!

// Advancing date by a month, to get end of next month.
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: myDate)  // "Feb 29, 2020 at 12:00 AM"
```

In the example above, you can see how to advance date by a month.

If the user chooses say the 31 of a month, the calendar automatically calculates the end of the next month accurately, even if it has only 28, 29, 30 or 31 days.

Comment: Your answer is great but it has one flaw, when you continue adding months to the date, and in your example, if you add one more month to your last date which was Feb 29, the next date will be March 29, which is not the end of the month.

Comment: Not necessarily. What if you do this :

`Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 2, to: myDate)  
// "Mar 31, 2020 at 12:00 AM"

Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 3, to: myDate)  
// "Apr 30, 2020 at 12:00 AM"`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use remote notifications and handle them on a server.  This would involve a bit more work and a server, but it is more flexible and allows you to change the notifications without the user needing an app update.  Link to the Apple Doc for [Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html).

The other option would be the use [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar).

When you do your logic to send the notification, you can test if today is the last day of the month.  If the user chooses to get the notifications on the 31st, and say today is the last day of the month and is the 30th, you can still send the notification because you know there isn't a 31st in this specific month.

Comment: I was thinking the same way, i already have a function which calculates the right date in these cases, but that way i have to schedule the notifications manually, and then i must face the 64 limit. and if i could use 'UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: calendarComponents, repeats: true)' because repeated notifications count as one.

Comment: @ElliotCzigány The year has only 12 months do you really need to schedule a notification after that?

Comment: You might need to go the multiple notification route. Don't add all of them at once though.  Maybe only add a few months in advanced.  You can always call `removeAllDeliveredNotifications()`.  That should free you from your limit as you go.  I haven't used that so you might need to do some investigation there.

Comment: @Derek Not all days start at midnight so if you get 1 am add a day and subtract 1 second it wont work

Comment: @LeoDabus True, and I removed it anyway since its not relevant to the question.